# Clever way to add the same parameter to mulitple locations in a prepared-statement

Tags: java, jdbc, union, prepared-statement

I have a JDBC query like

```
select * from table1 where col1 between x and y
union all
select * from table2 where col1 between x and y
union all
select * from table3 where col1 between x and y
```

I'm using a prepared-statement and am wondering if there is a cleverer way to set x and y without saying `setDate(1, x);setDate(2, y);setDate(3, x);`

Answer (score 0):

Cleverer.  Maybe a loop?  A for loop that executes three times and calls:

```
setDate((1*2)+1, x);
setDate((1*2)+2, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is decent, you can do:

```
select * from (
select * from table1 
union all
select * from table2
union all
select * from table3
)
where col1 between x and y
```

and pass `x` and `y` just once. The optimizer would apply the predicate to each table if appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

why be "clever"? Clever code usually results in "clever" bugs in "clever" corner cases.

BTW if you use hibernate, your query would be:

```
select * from table1 where col1 between :x and :y
union all
select * from table2 where col1 between :x and :y
union all
select * from table3 where col1 between :x and :y
```

Java code would look like this:

```
Query query;
query.setParameter("x", x);
query.setParameter("y", y);
```

Answer (score -3):

I would take advantage of java's String Formatter:

```
String queryFormat = "select * from table1 where col1 between %1$s and %2$s " +
                     "union all " +
                     "select * from table2 where col1 between %1$s and %2$s " +
                     "union all " +
                     "select * from table3 where col1 between %1$s and %2$s";
String query = String.format(queryFormat,"5","10");
```

The first argument passed to the format method is the format string.  The `%1$s` means to insert the **1**st argument of type **s**tring ("5"), and the `%2$s` means to insert the **2**nd argument of type **s**tring ("10").

The query string will then contain:

```
select * from table1 where col1 between 5 and 10 union all select * from table2 where col1 between 5 and 10 union all select * from table3 where col1 between 5 and 10
```

You can read more about the Formatter class [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Hope this helps.